# c# mocking EF6 context and dealing with auto increment primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-6

Has anyone found a good way to get auto-increment primary keys in a mocked context to work when testing service layers?

In most cases, seeding the primary key as part of the data to test is possible. But many service layer methods deal with creating multiple objects or linking other processes together that quickly fail if you are not responsible for passing all of the created data in. I thought of maybe adding a Callback() to SaveChangesAsync() that looks at the data created, and auto-generates a primary key incrementally but it won't be simple to implement.

```
var organization = new PrivateOrganization();
organization.Name = "New Test Organization";
organization.Description = "New Test Organization description";
organization.OrganizationTypeId = ITNOrganizationTypes.Agency;
organization.OrganizationStatusTypeId = (int)ITNOrganizationStatusTypes.Enabled;
organization.ShortCode = "Test";

var newOrg = await _service.InsertPrivateOrganizationAsync(organization);

_mockPrivateOrganizationsSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PrivateOrganization>()), Times.Once());
MockTenantContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(), Times.Once());

// validation passes, but contains no auto-generated primary key.
```

Comment: Did you ever find any answer to this?

Comment: I wrote a solution for this, I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to develop my own solution for this as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A helper class for managing custom behaviors of Mockable database contexts
/// </summary>
public static partial class EFSaveChangesBehaviors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enable auto-incrementing of primary key values upon SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of context to enable auto-incrementing on</typeparam>
    /// <param name="context">The context to enable this feature</param>
    public static void EnableAutoIncrementOnSave<T>(this Mock<T> context) where T : DbContext
    {
        context.Setup(m => m.SaveChangesAsync())
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                EFSaveChangesBehaviors.SaveChangesIncrementKey(context.Object);
            })
            .Returns(() => Task.Run(() => { return 1; }))
            .Verifiable();

        context.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges())
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                EFSaveChangesBehaviors.SaveChangesIncrementKey(context.Object);
            })
            .Returns(() => { return 1; })
            .Verifiable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements key incrementing of data records that are pending to be added to the context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public static void SaveChangesIncrementKey(DbContext context)
    {
        var tablesWithNewData = GetUnsavedRows<DbContext>(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < tablesWithNewData.Count; i++)
        {
            long nextPrimaryKeyValue = 0;
            var tableWithDataProperty = tablesWithNewData[i];
            var tableWithDataObject = tableWithDataProperty.GetValue(context);
            if (tableWithDataObject != null)
            {
                var tableWithDataQueryable = tableWithDataObject as IQueryable<object>;

                // 1) get the highest value in the DbSet<> (table) to continue auto-increment from
                nextPrimaryKeyValue = IterateAndPerformAction(context, tableWithDataQueryable, tableWithDataProperty, nextPrimaryKeyValue, (primaryExistingKeyValue, primaryKeyRowObject, primaryKeyProperty) =>
                {
                    if (primaryExistingKeyValue > nextPrimaryKeyValue)
                        nextPrimaryKeyValue = Convert.ToInt64(primaryExistingKeyValue);
                    return nextPrimaryKeyValue;
                });

                // 2) increase the value of the record's primary key on each iteration
                IterateAndPerformAction(context, tableWithDataQueryable, tableWithDataProperty, nextPrimaryKeyValue, (primaryKeyExistingValue, primaryKeyRowObject, primaryKeyProperty) =>
                {
                    if (primaryKeyExistingValue == 0)
                    {
                        nextPrimaryKeyValue++;
                        Type propertyType = primaryKeyProperty.PropertyType;
                        if (propertyType == typeof(Int64))
                            primaryKeyProperty.SetValue(primaryKeyRowObject, nextPrimaryKeyValue);
                        else if (propertyType == typeof(Int32))
                            primaryKeyProperty.SetValue(primaryKeyRowObject, Convert.ToInt32(nextPrimaryKeyValue));
                        else if (propertyType == typeof(Int16))
                            primaryKeyProperty.SetValue(primaryKeyRowObject, Convert.ToInt16(nextPrimaryKeyValue));
                        else if (propertyType == typeof(byte))
                            primaryKeyProperty.SetValue(primaryKeyRowObject, Convert.ToByte(nextPrimaryKeyValue));
                        else
                            throw new System.NotImplementedException($"Cannot manage primary keys of type: {propertyType.FullName}");
                    }
                    return nextPrimaryKeyValue;
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of properties for a data table that are indicated as a primary key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks>Reflection must be used, as the ObjectContext is not mockable</remarks>
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPrimaryKeyNamesUsingReflection(Type t, DbContext context)
    {
        var properties = t.GetProperties();
        var keyNames = properties
            .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute)))
            .ToArray();

        return keyNames;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Iterates a table's data and allows an action to be performed on each row
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The database context</param>
    /// <param name="tableWithDataQueryable"></param>
    /// <param name="tableWithDataProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="nextPrimaryKeyValue"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static long IterateAndPerformAction(DbContext context, IQueryable<object> tableWithDataQueryable, PropertyInfo tableWithDataProperty, long nextPrimaryKeyValue, Func<long, object, PropertyInfo, long> action)
    {
        foreach (var primaryKeyRowObject in tableWithDataQueryable)
        {
            // create a primary key for the object
            if (tableWithDataProperty.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Length > 0)
            {
                var dbSetType = tableWithDataProperty.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                // find the primary key property
                var primaryKeyProperty = GetPrimaryKeyNamesUsingReflection(dbSetType, context).FirstOrDefault();
                if (primaryKeyProperty != null)
                {
                    var primaryKeyValue = primaryKeyProperty.GetValue(primaryKeyRowObject) ?? 0L;
                    nextPrimaryKeyValue = action(Convert.ToInt64(primaryKeyValue), primaryKeyRowObject, primaryKeyProperty);
                }
            }
        }
        return nextPrimaryKeyValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of objects which are pending to be added to the context
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IList<PropertyInfo> GetUnsavedRows<T>(T context)
    {
        // get list of properties of type DbSet<>
        var dbSetProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var setType = property.PropertyType;
            var isDbSet = setType.IsGenericType && (typeof(IDbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(setType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) || setType.GetInterface(typeof(IDbSet<>).FullName) != null);
            if (isDbSet)
            {
                dbSetProperties.Add(property);
            }
        }

        return dbSetProperties;
    }


}
```

Usage:

```
// enable auto-increment in our in-memory database
MockTenantContext.EnableAutoIncrementOnSave();
```